# cakephp 3 paginate on union

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I have a union

```
$myContacts = $this->Contacts->find()
        ->matching('Users', function($q) {
                return $q->where(['Users.id' => 3]);
            });
$inmygroupsContacts = $this->Contacts->find()
        ->matching('Groups', function($q){
                return $q->where(['Groups.id' => 5]);
            });
$contacts = $myContacts->union($inmygroupsContacts);
```

I would like to paginate the results.

$this->paginate($contacts) gives me en error: Error: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

I tried to call $contacts->execute() and $contacts->all() before paginating but than I get an other error: Error: Call to undefined method Cake\Database\Log\LoggingStatement::alias()

How to do it?

Comment: Can't test it right now, but I can imagine two possible sources of errors, mismatchig column count on the `users` and `groups` tables, and the unionized selects not being used as a subquery in the queries issued by the paginator.

Comment: $contacts->toArray() gives me the right results. So your second guess is right. But what to do with that?

Comment: It seems to be a bug https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5107